# getting all notifications

Tags: facebook-graph-api, notifications

I can easily get the unread notifications with this query:
`https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/notifications?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`
Is it possible to all the notifications (marked as read) too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can specify the parameter include_read as 1 to indicate you wish to receive read notifications.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/notifications?include_read=1&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Answer (score -1):

this link may be help you
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/notifications-api/

Using The API

Applications can generate notifications by issuing a HTTP POST request to the /user_id/notifications Graph API, with a app access_token.

POST /{recipient_userid}/notifications?access_token= … &template= … &href= …

Comment: This has nothing to do with the user's question and merely references irrelevant documentation.  The user does not want to push notifications from games, he wants to pull in read notifications from his user...